# What is the taboo against "fox"?

Tags: meaning

On the Wiki page for [自贡话民俗特色词汇列表](https://zh.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E8%87%AA%E8%B4%A1%E8%AF%9D%E6%B0%91%E4%BF%97%E7%89%B9%E8%89%B2%E8%AF%8D%E6%B1%87%E5%88%97%E8%A1%A8) there's an entry that says:

> - 毛狗：狐狸(民间因犯忌讳而改称)。

What is the taboo against 狐狸 (fox) though?

Is there some relation to 狸 being a homophone with 利?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The taboo is just due to the general view that foxes are inauspicious/trickster/fierce animals.

Reference 1 (https://new.qq.com/omn/20171112/20171112A08Q1T.html):

> **蜀话中的忌讳说凶恶动物**，例如蛇在四川话中的讳称有“梭老二”、“梭梭”、“干黄鳝”、“长虫”等，老虎在四川话中的讳称有“猫猫”、“大猫”、“大头猫”、“扁担花”等，**狐狸在四川话中的讳称为“毛狗”，老鼠在鼠话中的讳称有“耗子”、“老水子”、“高客”、“喜马”等**。

Reference 2 (https://wenku.baidu.com/view/7890ddc05fbfc77da269b180.html):

> 俗传狐狸成精后,会变成女人害人,故成都、重庆、南川、阆中、泸州、西充、綦江、金堂、仪陇、云阳等地改称为“毛 狗”。

Comment: I thought there would be more to it. The wiki link I put in my question also mentions that: `老鼠。此词因自贡民俗中忌讳说“鼠”(谐音“输”）而改称。` Snake I’ve heard being taboo because it sounds like 蚀.

Comment: @user3306356 I guess the real reason for the taboo will be lost in folk etymology...